# Type kannada language in html textbox or input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html form...It contains combination of some 15 - 20 input and textarea fields....As a user how to enter all these input fields in kananda/or any other local language??

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1):

1. The user should have Baraha Direct / BarahaIME installed.
2. "Kannada Comment" wordpress plugin allows you to type in Kannada directly in the wordpress sites. You could also try similar technique for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Not-Wordpress ideas:
If you want to serve multiple languages, serve also multiple pages and then:
a: You should instruct to use the right charset in the header of the document like `<meta charset="Shift_JIS">` = HalfWidthKatakana. Search for declarations for other charsets at [http://www.iana.org/](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)
b: You should declare the specific language in the html tag like `<html lang="kn">`.
(Search for declarations for other languages at [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp))